# Return all possible prediction values

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

This neural network trains on inputs `[[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0]]` with labelled outputs : `[[0.0], [1.0], [1.0], [0.0]]`

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(init)
# a batch of inputs of 2 value each
inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2])

# a batch of output of 1 value each
desired_outputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])

# [!] define the number of hidden units in the first layer
HIDDEN_UNITS = 4 
weights_1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([2, HIDDEN_UNITS]))

biases_1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([HIDDEN_UNITS]))

# connect 2 inputs to every hidden unit. Add bias
layer_1_outputs = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(inputs, weights_1) + biases_1)

print layer_1_outputs

NUMBER_OUTPUT_NEURONS = 1

biases_2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([NUMBER_OUTPUT_NEURONS]))
weights_2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([HIDDEN_UNITS, NUMBER_OUTPUT_NEURONS]))
finalLayerOutputs = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(layer_1_outputs, weights_2) + biases_2)

tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

logits = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(layer_1_outputs, weights_2) + biases_2)

training_inputs = [[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0]]
training_outputs = [[0.0], [1.0], [1.0], [0.0]]

error_function = 0.5 * tf.reduce_sum(tf.sub(logits, desired_outputs) * tf.sub(logits, desired_outputs))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.05).minimize(error_function)

for i in range(15):
    _, loss = sess.run([train_step, error_function],
                       feed_dict={inputs: np.array(training_inputs),
                                  desired_outputs: np.array(training_outputs)})

print(sess.run(logits, feed_dict={inputs: np.array([[0.0, 1.0]])}))
```

Upon training this network returns `[[ 0.61094815]]` for values `[[0.0, 1.0]]`

`[[ 0.61094815]]` is value with highest probability after training this network is assign to input value [[0.0, 1.0]] ? Can the lower probability values also be accessed and not just most probable ?

If I increase number of training epochs I'll get better prediction but in this case I just want to access all potential values with their probabilities for a given input.

Update :

Have updated code to use multi class classification with softmax. But the prediction for `[[0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]]` is `[array([0])]`. Have I updated correctly ?

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(init)
# a batch of inputs of 2 value each
inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 4])

# a batch of output of 1 value each
desired_outputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 3])

# [!] define the number of hidden units in the first layer
HIDDEN_UNITS = 4 
weights_1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([4, HIDDEN_UNITS]))

biases_1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([HIDDEN_UNITS]))

# connect 2 inputs to every hidden unit. Add bias
layer_1_outputs = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(inputs, weights_1) + biases_1)

biases_2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([3]))
weights_2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([HIDDEN_UNITS, 3]))
finalLayerOutputs = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(layer_1_outputs, weights_2) + biases_2)

tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

logits = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(layer_1_outputs, weights_2) + biases_2)

training_inputs = [[0.0, 0.0 , 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0 , 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0 , 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0 , 0.0, 0.0]]
training_outputs = [[0.0,0.0,0.0], [1.0,0.0,0.0], [1.0,0.0,0.0], [0.0,0.0,1.0]]

error_function = 0.5 * tf.reduce_sum(tf.sub(logits, desired_outputs) * tf.sub(logits, desired_outputs))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.05).minimize(error_function)

for i in range(15):
    _, loss = sess.run([train_step, error_function],
                       feed_dict={inputs: np.array(training_inputs),
                                  desired_outputs: np.array(training_outputs)})

prediction=tf.argmax(logits,1)
best = sess.run([prediction],feed_dict={inputs: np.array([[0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]])})
print(best)
```

Which prints `[array([0])]`

Update 2 :

Replacing

```
prediction=tf.argmax(logits,1)
best = sess.run([prediction],feed_dict={inputs: np.array([[0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]])})
print(best)
```

With  :

```
prediction=tf.nn.softmax(logits)
best = sess.run([prediction],feed_dict={inputs: np.array([[0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]])})
print(best)
```

Appears to fix issue.

So now full source is :

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(init)
# a batch of inputs of 2 value each
inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 4])

# a batch of output of 1 value each
desired_outputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 3])

# [!] define the number of hidden units in the first layer
HIDDEN_UNITS = 4 
weights_1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([4, HIDDEN_UNITS]))

biases_1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([HIDDEN_UNITS]))

# connect 2 inputs to every hidden unit. Add bias
layer_1_outputs = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(inputs, weights_1) + biases_1)

biases_2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([3]))
weights_2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([HIDDEN_UNITS, 3]))
finalLayerOutputs = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(layer_1_outputs, weights_2) + biases_2)

tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

logits = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(layer_1_outputs, weights_2) + biases_2)

training_inputs = [[0.0, 0.0 , 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0 , 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0 , 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0 , 0.0, 0.0]]
training_outputs = [[0.0,0.0,0.0], [1.0,0.0,0.0], [1.0,0.0,0.0], [0.0,0.0,1.0]]

error_function = 0.5 * tf.reduce_sum(tf.sub(logits, desired_outputs) * tf.sub(logits, desired_outputs))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.05).minimize(error_function)

for i in range(1500):
    _, loss = sess.run([train_step, error_function],
                       feed_dict={inputs: np.array(training_inputs),
                                  desired_outputs: np.array(training_outputs)})

prediction=tf.nn.softmax(logits)
best = sess.run([prediction],feed_dict={inputs: np.array([[0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]])})
print(best)
```

Which prints

```
[array([[ 0.49810624,  0.24845563,  0.25343812]], dtype=float32)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current network does (logistic) regression, not really classification: given an input `x`, it tries to evaluate `f(x)` (where `f(x) = x1 XOR x2` here, but the network does not know that before training), which is regression. To do so, it learns a function `f1(x)` and tries to have it be as close to `f(x)` on all your training samples. `[[ 0.61094815]]` is just the value of `f1([[0.0, 1.0]])`. In this setting, there is no such thing as "probability to be in a class", since there is no class. There is only the user (you) chosing to interpret `f1(x)` as a probability for the output to be 1. Since you have only 2 classes, that tells you that the probability of the other class is `1-0.61094815` (that is, you're doing classification with the output of the network, but it is not really trained to do that in itself). This method used as classification is, in a way, a (widely used) trick to perform classification, but only works if you have 2 classes.

A real network for classification would be built a bit differently: your logits would be of shape `(batch_size, number_of_classes)` - so (1, 2) in your case-, you apply a sofmax on them, and then the prediction is `argmax(softmax)`, with probability `max(softmax)`. Then you can also get the probability of each output, according to the network: `probability(class i) = softmax[i]`. Here the network is really trained to learn the probability of `x` being in each class.

I'm sorry if my explanation is obscure or if the difference between regression between 0 and 1 and classification seems philosophical in a setting with 2 classes, but if you add more classes you'll probably see what I mean.

**EDIT**
Answer to your 2 updates.

- in your training samples, the labels (training_outputs) must be probability distributions, i.e. they must have sum 1 for each sample (99% of the time they are of the form (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0) or (0, 0, 1)), so your first output [0.0,0.0,0.0] is not valid. If you want to learn XOR on the two first inputs, then the 1st output should be the same as the last: [0.0,0.0,1.0].
- `prediction=tf.argmax(logits,1) = [array([0])]` is completely normal: `logins`contains your probabilities, and `prediction` is the prediction, which is the class with the biggest probability, which is in your case class 0: in your training set, `[0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]` is associated with output `[1.0, 0.0, 0.0]`, i.e. it is of class 0 with probability 1, and of the other classes with probability 0. After enough training, `print(best)` with `prediction=tf.argmax(logits,1)` on input `[1.0, 1.0 , 0.0, 0.0]` should give you [array([2])], 2 being the index of the class for this input in your training set.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions which I've attempted to incorporate into neural network. Can you notice an issue with neural network in my question update ?

Comment: I think I've resolved issue and have updated question.